# Show that there are infinitely many values of α for which

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Show that there are infinitely many values of $\alpha$ for which $x^7 +15x^2-30x+\alpha$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: Is the first term supposed to be $x^3$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mean $f(x)=x^3+15x^2-30x+\alpha$.
If $\alpha$ is an odd number, then $f$ is irreducible modulo $2$.

---

Added after edit:

Alas $x^7+x^2+1$ is reducible modulo $2$, but cip999's idea of using
Eisenstein still works.

Comment: $\alpha = 3k$ with $(k, \: 3) = 1$ also works fine because of Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Sorry now i have edited the question

Comment: Can anyone give me a detailed explanation

Comment: Help me in this